# How to open an audio data

Tags: python, audio, m4a

I have a m4a file, and i want to open it...what should i do? i've tried the obvious

```
>>> q = open('file.m4a').read()
>>> len(q)
6989886
>>> print q[:10000]

>>>
```

It prints a blank line! i've tried to open the file with 'rb' flag but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes..i wonder to know why it doesnt work..

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work..'? What's the exact error message?

Comment: there was a comment before mine...however i was talking about read() and why read should not work on audio files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the `repr()` of the data:

```
>>> print repr(q[:10000])
```

If you print the data itself, it may contain control character or other unprintable text, which makes for misleading output. The Python `repr()` function makes that data readable by escaping the characters as needed.

In the interactive shell, the `repr()` value of the expression entered is printed if it isn't `None`. So this would do the same thing:

```
>>> q[:10000]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Python Audio Tools](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/install.html) ?

Comment: if i understood it allows you to do a lot of thing but hiding the method; i mean, there is a way to actually open that file to see what's in there?

Comment: For that you need at the very least to decode it using an m4a codec of some sort.

Comment: Well, yes, but they're written in C. One such can be found at: http://www.audiocoding.com/
But really Python Audio Tools should provide the kind of higher level interface you want.